# How can I add manipulate controls to this show?

Tags: manipulate

I would like to select any value for n, where p[x,y] = k^n

I have tried using the initialize function, but I am not exactly sure what is going wrong

Here is what I have tried so far

```
Clear[f, m, p, x, y, n]
f[x_] := -x + 6
m1[x_] := -(1/2) x + 3
m2[x_] := -2 x + 6
m3[x_] := 1


p1 = Plot[{f[x], m1[x], m2[x], m3[x]}, {x, 0, 6}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic];

Manipulate[
Show[p1, centroid],
{{n, 10, "value of n"}, 2, 20, 1 , Appearance -> "Labeled"}
Initialization :>
(

p[x_, y_] := k^n;

mass = Integrate[p[x, y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, p[x, y]}];
momentx = Integrate[p[x, y]*y, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, p[x, y]}];
momenty = Integrate[p[x, y]*x, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, p[x, y]}];
xbar = momenty/mass;
ybar = momentx/mass;
centroid = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{xbar, ybar}]}];

)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary issues (and a missing comma). For one your `k` is never defined, the more serious one is that all of your [`Initialization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Initialization.html) definitions are immediate and don't end up changing with the controls.

By moving the definitions into the actual `Show` expression you get a manipulable expression:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[p1,
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large],
    With[{p = Function[k^n]},
     With[{
       mass = Integrate[p[x, y], {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, p[x, y]}],
       momentx = Integrate[p[x, y]*y, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, p[x, y]}],
       momenty = Integrate[p[x, y]*x, {x, 0, 6}, {y, 0, p[x, y]}]
       },
      Point[{momentx, momenty}/mass]
      ]
     ]
    }]
  ],
 {{n, 10, "value of n"}, 2, 20, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {k, .01, 2}
 ]
```